# How to create 2 nodes with backup, but without document balance

Tags: couchbase

I have 2 couchbase nodes.

One should backup the other, but I do **NOT** want the server to balance the documents between them.

So I've tried to add them both to one cluster, and set replicas to "disable" on the bucket, but still it balance the documents between those 2 servers.

Then I've tried to use the servers as different clusters with replication between them.
I've also added in the client config those two servers:

```
<servers bucket="default" bucketPassword="private">
    <add uri="http://server1ip/pools/default">
    <add uri="http://server2ip/pools/default">
</servers>
```

When I shut down server1, the requests went to server2, so the backup worked!

**BUT** i'm not sure if I'm sending a request from a client on server1, it will always choose the nearest server (sending the request always to server1ip).

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating a Couchbase cluster, this is viewed as a "single" database. The data are always distributed in the same cluster.

So if you want to "backup" automatically the data into other nodes, what you have to use is the the XDCR (Cross Data Center Replication) that will replicate the data from one cluster to another cluster. (as you can see I am not using the word, "node", since a Couchbase database should be deployed on multipe nodes.)

I am inviting you to look at the following resources to learn more about this:

- Generic documentation on XDCR :
  http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.1.0/couchbase-admin-tasks-xdcr.html
- Webinar :    http://info.couchbase.com/webinar-couchbase-server-and-XDCR.html

Comment: Thanks for you comment. How can I use the second cluster I configure as a backup ? I mean, how can I define that my client will always send requests to cluster A, but will have cluster B as backup ?

Comment: So what you have to do here si simply put XDCR between the 2 clusters. So you application connect to ClusterA, and you put a one direction replication A & B using XDCR. You can take a look at : http://info.couchbase.com/webinar-couchbase-server-and-XDCR.html

Comment: But if I will have a client on Cluster A, will it always go to that server and not to B ?

Comment: Yes, and what you can do is, if the connection to cluster A is lost, you can catch it in your code and reconnect to the Cluster B.

Comment: How can I check if a connection is alive if I'm writing on C# ?
I couldn't find any API that checks if connection is alive. 
Can it be done only when trying to perform an action to Couchbase DB ?

Answer (score 0):

I would think a load balancer would help. You could put a load balancer in front of the two couchbase servers and direct each of the clients to the load balancer. If the load balancer has the ability, it could determine the preferred server based on something (ip address?). if the preferred server isn't available, it could go to the other one.

Comment: is there a way to acheive this without using a load balancer ?

Comment: no idea. i'm just providing a possible solution:) i can't think of another way to do what you want.

Comment: As said before, if you have a 2 nodes cluster you do not need a load balancer since they are part of the same "database" and the load will be managed by the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you add 2 servers in your config, I'm not sure that couchbase choose nearest server, it could just use roundrobin. But I've noticed, that servers order in configuration affects their load, so maybe just first server will have higher priority, but not all requests will go to it. And I haven't seen any configuration options for .Net client to set one of the servers like "main" and other like "backup". So maybe you can try:

1. Ask couchbase .net library developers on couchbase [forums](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/q-and-a) if there is some solution to set main and backup servers in configuration.
2. To use HA Proxy as middleware that will choose proper running server. (as Don Dickinson suggested)
3. Create two couchbase connections in your app (one for main server, one for backup: you'll need two config sections). If some operation fails on main server repeat request to backup. So your code will look like:

   var getResult = _ClientMain.ExecuteGet(key);
   if (!getResult.Sucess){
     getResult = _ClientBackup.ExecuteGet(key);
   }
4. Modify .Net clien library to satisfy your needs.